# Firebase Database [v6.2.4]: Snapshot not Exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following Firebase database:

[image]

I just want to retrieve a set of `Accounts` records and later bind it with `ng-repeat` as shown below:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="account in accounts">
    <td>{{ account.AccName }}</td>
    <td>{{ account.AccStatus }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I use the **Automatic** version of Firebase references and initialization as shown below, therefore no `apiKey` and `databaseURL` have been specified here:

```
<!-- update the version number as needed -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.2.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.2.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.2.4/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.2.4/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/6.2.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

When I do a simple check on the `snapshot`, it is always not exist (no runtime error whatsoever):

```
        // ref("Accounts") is my root ref as shown in picture above
        const accountsRef = firebase.database().ref("Accounts"); 

        accountsRef.once("value").then(function (snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log(snapshot.val());
            } else {
                console.log("Snapshot not exist!");
            }

        })
```

I tried `ref("/Accounts")` and `ref("Accounts/")` but no luck. Sorry that I'm very new to Firebase real-time database. I just want to know:

1. How can I retrieve a record set for my `Accounts` database table and bind it with `ng-repeat` as shown above?
2. Have I structured my data wrongly (see screenshot)? Note that `OTK-001` is an **unique account code** for each record in the `Accounts` table/collection.
3. Do I still need to add the old Firebase config with `apiKey` and `databaseURL` like the old way? (NOTE: Tried before, not working.)

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt you're using firestore and your code is mostly likely querying firebase. See my answer

Comment: Oops.... I think you're right, just noticed it on my Firebase Console, thanks a lot! Sorry for my negligence!

Comment: No Problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore querying is like the below

collection reference for firestore is

```
let collectionRef = firestore.collection('col/doc/subcollection');
```

Fetching the data is

```
 async getAccountData() {
        const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('accounts').get()
        return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    }
```